# After insert trigger on Attachment object doesnt fire

Tags: attachment

Was anyone successful in getting their after insert trigger on Attachment working? I don't see any debug logs for the trigger when I try to invoke from the UI

Updating post to add my code:

```
trigger AttachmentTrigger on Attachment (after insert) {
   Map<id,List<Attachment>> taskAttachmentMap = new Map<id,List<Attachment>>();
    for(Attachment attachment: [SELECT Body,BodyLength,ContentType,Description,Id,IsPrivate,Name,ParentId FROM Attachment where Id IN :Trigger.new]){           
        String text= String.valueof(attachment.ParentId);
        if(text.startswith('00T')){
            List<Attachment> la = new List<Attachment>();
            if(taskAttachmentMap.get(attachment.parentId)==null){
                la.add(attachment);
            }else{
                la = taskAttachmentMap.get(attachment.parentId);
                la.add(attachment);
            }
            taskAttachmentMap.put(attachment.parentId, la);                     
        }

    }

    List<Attachment> attachmentsToInsertonOpp = new List<Attachment>();
    //Find all tasks that are associated to opportunities
    if(taskAttachmentMap!=null){
        for(Task t: [select id, whatid from Task where id IN :taskAttachmentMap.keyset()]){
                String text1 = String.valueof(t.whatid);
                if(text1.startswith('006')){
                    for(Attachment att:taskAttachmentMap.get(t.id) ){
                        att.parentid=t.whatid;
                        attachmentsToInsertonOpp.add(att);                        
                    }
                }
        }           

    }

    //Now insert attachments
    if(attachmentsToInsertonOpp.size()!=0){
        insert attachmentsToInsertonOpp;
    }


}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do in the after insert event ? What actually do you see in the debug logs ?

Comment: I have an `After Insert` trigger working on `Attachment` in my company's orgs. Please edit your question to include more details.

Comment: I am trying to copy an attachment attached to a task on Opportunity to Note and attachments section of opportunity itself. Here is the code:

Comment: @user28253 welcome to the community.  Make sure that when you post questions that you provide information on what you have tried and your current code. This will prevent your question from being voted down and help you get an answer quicker. Welcome!

Comment: @BlairKristin Thanks! Code i am trying to add is too long for the post

Comment: (1) you may run into heap issues with batch insert of many attachments; to be robust, you'll need to use an async pattern (2) The test for object type can be simpler and more robust/transparent - for any variable of type ID, say `attachment.parentId`, you can do `if (attachment.parentId.getSobjectType() == Schema.Task.SobjectType) {..}`; (3) no need to test for size of `attachmentsToInsertOnOpp` before insert. Empty lists can be inserted at no cost in DML limits

Comment: Other than some inefficiencies, your included code seems fine. Are you sure the `Trigger` is `Active`?

Comment: Thanks @crop1645! Yes the trigger is active @Adrian Larson

Comment: I am not sure if this will work as I am clicking on 'save' button of task to save the attchment - should i be writing the trigger on task? but, i haven't figured out any logic for that :-o

Comment: Tried Opening a case with Salesforce and they have listed this as a bug and still in R&D. Here's the link. https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008YpjAAE  I am stuck forever.

Answer (score -1):

Salesforce provides an example of an after insert trigger in the following link http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000181538 . Here is the answer they provide.

A trigger can be written on Attachment using Force.com IDE or ANT.

A sample code would be:

```
trigger SetTitleToAttachment on Attachment (after insert) {

String Title;
Id pId;

for(Attachment att: Trigger.new){
Title=att.Name;
pId=att.ParentId;
}

List<Case> c=[select Id , Title__c from Case where Id=:pId];

//assuming one record is fetched.
c[0].Title__c=Title;

update c[0];

}
```

Note: There is no way to write a trigger using the Salesforce.com UI (Portal).

Comment: Thanks everyone! Please find the code in the post. This code doesnt seem to get invoked at all. Any ideas?